# How can I perform syndrome measurements for both X-type and Z-type stabilizers in Stim?

Tags: measurement, error-correction, stabilizer-code, noise, stim

I would like to simulate the logical error rate of the surface code under depolarizing noise using Stim. The decoder I am using decodes from both X-type and Z-type stabilizer syndrome values. Specifically, if an X error occurs on one data qubit, the syndrome value of the Z-type stabilizer flips. If a Z error occurs, the syndrome value of the X-type stabilizer flips. If a Y error occurs, both the X-type and Z-type stabilizer syndrome values flip.

I am considering the situation where both X-type and Z-type stabilizer syndrome measurements are performed. However, in the `surface_code:rotated_memory_z` instruction, even though depolarizing noise is generated, it seems that only the Z-type stabilizer measurement is performed. Why is that? Also, how can I perform syndrome measurements for both X-type and Z-type stabilizers?

Comment: All of stim's generated circuits measure all the stabilizers of the code. `stim.Circuit.generated("surface_code:rotated_memory_z")` measures both X and Z stabilizers. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: It is because all data qubits are initialized to |0> at the start, so the circuit can’t catch the Z errors. Z errors don’t change the state of |0>. Isn't that correct?

Comment: And, if it is true that it measures both X and Z stabilizers, what is the meaning of memory_z?

Comment: @Ian The first stabilizer measurement (before the loop in the stim circuit), transforms the $|0\rangle$ state into a codestate. That's the encoding. The measurements inside the loop are then error detections.

Comment: @Ian The circuit is initializing and measuring the Z logical observable (that's the _z in the name). That's very different from it not measuring all the stabilizers. It still measures all the stabilizers. You might think that measuring the X stabilizers is useless, but actually they can be used to get hints about where Y errors are occurring. Also it would be blatantly cheating on the benchmark to omit the X stabilizer measurements, because the bulk of the circuit has to be identical regardless of the state being protected. That's how you know it works on any state, not just Z or X eigenstates

Comment: @Abdullah Khalid
Thank you. It is said that the first stabilizer measurement is for encoding, but in round 9, there is a REPEAT 2, then REPEAT 7. Does this mean that it is encoding with REPEAT 2? If so, why is it repeated twice instead of once?

Comment: @Craig Gidney
So, do you mean that the circuit `surface_code:rotated_memory_z` produce both the syndrome values of X-type and Z-type stabilizers?  I don't know which measurement of the circuit corresponds to the syndrome values of X-type and Z-type stabilizers, respectively.

Comment: @Ian use stim.Circuit.diagram to look at the circuit. You can figure out which measurement qubits are which by tracking how they interact with the data qubits.

Comment: @Craig Gidney I appreciate your very kind response. Thank you.